# How can I add my custom fields into the content of my posts?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, storefront

Please forgive me if my phrasing is confusing. I am pretty new to PHP and still don't understand it very well.

I am editing content-single.php on my child theme of storefront.
I have made some custom fields and I would like them to be located inside the content of my post.

but I can only manage to get it above or below the content.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template used to display post content on single pages.
 *
 * @package storefront
 */

?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    
    <?php
    do_action( 'storefront_single_post_top' );
    
    the_field('test');

    /**
     * Functions hooked into storefront_single_post add_action
     *
     * @hooked storefront_post_header          - 10
     * @hooked storefront_post_content         - 30
     */

    do_action( 'storefront_single_post' );

    
    /**
     * Functions hooked in to storefront_single_post_bottom action
     *
     * @hooked storefront_post_nav         - 10
     * @hooked storefront_display_comments - 20
     */
    do_action( 'storefront_single_post_bottom' );
    ?>
    

</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did that solution work for you?

Comment: So far I can not get that solution to work. I might also mention that I am using this for a custom post type with the slug: review.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in functions.php

```
     add_filter('storefront_post_content', 'add_acf', 10, 1);

function add_acf( $value ) {
$value = get_field('test');
return $value;
```

};

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using elementor for this particular issue